# Allocated memory growth on web servers

Tags: algorithm, web-applications, memory-management, computer-science

I am trying to create a web application where the memory allocated can at times grow exponentially and  would like to estimate how much maximum memory can be allocated by an application on a web server at any given time, so that it would still run normally. Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `np` is not a proper tag for this question. I do not think this is a NP problem :)

Comment: +1 for amazing definition of NP :)

Comment: the question seems like "when does the server run out of memory?", nothing to do with the application - even if the word exponentially is used.

Comment: I interpret the question as -- "how much memory to allocate to ensure web-application never runs out of memory"

Answer (score 1):

You can use binary search type technique in your experiments. You have to run experiments to see how much memory you need. Start with an educated guess and use binary search to increase or decrease till you are satisfied. Is there anything specific you are asking?